# Editable JComboBox limit length

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

i have an editable JCombobox and need to set a limit to the number of characters that can be set by the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentions characters, I assume the editor on your `JCombobox` can be a `JTextField`. In that case, you can limit the number of characters the `JTextField` accepts by setting a custom `Document`, as explained in full detail [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0198.html)

Comment: @Cesar, That is old code. The newer approach would be to use a [Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify maximum number of characters changing the comboBox editor as you can see below (**Max 4** characters):

```js
JComboBox comboBox==new JComboBox();
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboBox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
textField.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(4));
```